# Optimizing a Pine script to avoid repaints and allow for short trade

Tags: pine-script

I am wondering if there would be an easy way to optimize this script to allow for no repaints, and if possible, short entries:

```
strategy("P&F scalp strat", shorttitle="MEXlongOnly_strat", overlay=true)

timeframe = input('1')

box = input('Traditional')

boxsize = input(1, type=float)

reversal = input(1)

pnf = pointfigure(tickerid, 'close', box, boxsize, reversal)

pnf_open= security(pnf, timeframe , open)

pnf_close= security(pnf, timeframe , close)

p1 = plot(pnf_open, title="pnf_open", color=green)

p2 = plot(pnf_close,  title="pnf_close",color=maroon)

base = pnf_close> pnf_open? pnf_close: pnf_open

p0 = plot(base, title="base", color=gray)

fill(p0, p1, color=green, transp=70)

fill(p0, p2, color=maroon, transp=70)

entry() => (base > pnf_open)

exit() => (base > pnf_close)

alertcondition(entry(), title='buy', message='buy!')

alertcondition(exit(), title='sell', message='sell!')

strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)

strategy.entry("Long", long=true, when=entry())

strategy.entry("close", false, when=exit())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these `security()` calls to avoid repainting:

```
pnf_open= security(pnf, timeframe , open[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
pnf_close= security(pnf, timeframe , close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

See [How to avoid repainting when using security()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).